# React useState setter in promise not updating

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I'm trying to update a usestate count in axios response, its not working correctly.

```
let [ validationCount , setValidationCount ] = useState(0);


function getValidationResponse(validationUrl:string, validationKey:string)
    {
           axios.get("https://test.com/health")
                .then(res => {
                    setValidationCount(validationCount+1);
                }).catch(err => {
                
            });
            
        return "";
    }
```

above function gets called twice but validation count is always 1.

is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how `getValidationResponse` is used, I suspect there might be a issue with closure that captures `validationCount` as `0` resulting the updated value to be `1` always.

Try using [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) which will update the value of `validationCount` based on the previous value.

```js
setValidationCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1);
```

Comment: thanks  , how can we do the same for objects?  
let [ validationState, setValidationState ] = useState({} as { [key:string]:string});

Comment: `setValidationState(prev => ({ ...prev, key1: value1 }))`

Answer (score 0):

It's a closure problem, you can see it in action [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/button-set-state-test-wi577?file=/index.js), basically, if you click on it slowly, it works fine, if you click on it multiple times before the previous update is concluded, you create functions where validationCount still hasn't updated. It's always good to remember that setState is an async function.

Comment: For more info about this, you can refer to [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).